# Jekyll Liquid::Block output HTML

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I am very new to Ruby and Liquid, but couldn't find an anweser neither here nor googling.

What I want to achieve is/should be super simple. I want to write:

```
{% start %}
Some html <a href="#">here</a>.
{% endstart %}
```

And Jekyll should output this like:

```
<div class="start">
Some html <a href="#">here</a>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't strictly necessary, as you don't gain very much by not writing the `div` yourself. If you really want to do it, you can [write a Jekyll plugin](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#tags).

If writing all the HTML boilerplate is too much (it usually is argh), you should use [Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/), which is a plugin that greatly simplifies inserting these tags or consider using something like [HAML](http://haml.info/).